# Como aplicar o teste de Pettitt no R?

Tags: r

Boa noite, pessoal.
Estou tentando aplicar o teste de Pettitt a uma série de dados. Estou utilizando o pacote `trend` no `R`. Só que o resultado encontrado não é o que eu estou procurando, que é o que segue abaixo:

```
> pettitt.test(URB_out_ts)

    Pettitt's test for single change-point detection

data:  URB_out_ts
K = 132, p-value = 0.3587
alternative hypothesis: true change point is present in the series
sample estimates:
probable change point at tau 
                      34
```

Eu gostaria de obter um resultado semelhante ao da figura abaixo. Só que procurei a função no pacote `TSA` e não existe. Alguém sabe como obter esse resultado?
[image: Resultado do teste de Pettitt]

Comment: A linha `pettitt(larain)` dá erro: `Error in pettitt(larain) : could not find function "pettitt"`. Pode nos mostrar o código exato que usou para obter o output da pergunta?

Comment: O que eu usei foi o "pettitt.test". Esse de baixo eu achei na internet, mas não consegui executar nem achei nenhum pacote com o comando "pettitt".

Comment: O que encontrou na internet foi no [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69501/implementing-pettitt-test-in-r/223192). Inclui duas funções semelhantes, a que dá essa imagem e outra mais abaixo. É só copiar para uma sessão do `R` e executar.